# Batch Script: IF NOT EXIST fails for file check when executed through wix ExePackage

Tags: batch-file, wix, bootstrapper

I am executing a batch file to check if particular file is present or not using `IF NOT EXIST` clause through wix bundle. it looks like below

```
@echo off

set EMS_INSTALL_ROOT="C:\Program Files (x86)\TOOLS\EMS\swVersion.txt"

IF NOT EXIST "%EMS_INSTALL_ROOT%" (
    exit 1
)

set /p Version=<"%EMS_INSTALL_ROOT%"
REG ADD HKCU\CurrentSwVersion /v SwVersion /t REG_SZ /d %VERSION% /f

exit 0
```

and the bundle.wxs file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
      xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
      xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

    <Bundle Name='Language Installer 1.0'
        Version='1.0'
        UpgradeCode='{CFA901F4-F22D-4826-AF17-CEF08636626A}'
        Manufacturer='xxx'>

        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication 
                LicenseFile="license.rtf"
                SuppressOptionsUI ="yes"
                />
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

        <Chain>
            <ExePackage SourceFile="sw_version_check.bat" Compressed="yes"/>
            <MsiPackage SourceFile="multilang.msi" Compressed="yes" DisplayInternalUI='yes'/>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

So, when i execute the same batch file form outside, like on command prompt it `returns 0` and when i run the same through bundle it `returns 1`. 
This is the log that i get from bundle

```
[1140:00EC][2017-11-10T09:46:46]i305: Verified acquired payload: sw_version_check.bat at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\sw_version_check.bat, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\F791A31D2DE729790CB77093BD38CF43E3FDA802\sw_version_check.bat.
[1140:00EC][2017-11-10T09:46:46]i304: Verified existing payload: multilang.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{EBB4657C-1AE5-423A-B2E4-2F0E6738BF2F}v1.0.0.0\multilang.msi.
[1140:0E20][2017-11-10T09:46:46]i301: Applying execute package: sw_version_check.bat, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\F791A31D2DE729790CB77093BD38CF43E3FDA802\sw_version_check.bat, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\F791A31D2DE729790CB77093BD38CF43E3FDA802\sw_version_check.bat"'
[1140:0E20][2017-11-10T09:46:46]e000: Error 0x80070001: Process returned error: 0x1
[1140:0E20][2017-11-10T09:46:46]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to execute EXE package.
[0DB8:0DC8][2017-11-10T09:46:46]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[0DB8:0DC8][2017-11-10T09:46:46]i319: Applied execute package: sw_version_check.bat, result: 0x80070001, restart: None
[0DB8:0DC8][2017-11-10T09:46:46]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to execute EXE package.
```

I have even tried to `run as admin` on bundle.exe but getting same result.

So, Could some one tell me what i am doing wrong here?

**EDIT 1**

As per the suggestion by @Squashman i made change in the example script and it worked but the same thing i applied for my dynamic script it again started failing. it looks like

```
@echo off

FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\MANBW" /v "ROOT" 2^>nul`) DO (
    set ValueName=%%A
    set ValueType=%%B
    set "ECS_INSTALL_ROOT=%%CswVersion.txt"
)

IF NOT EXIST "%ECS_INSTALL_ROOT%" (
    exit 1
)

set /p Version=<"%ECS_INSTALL_ROOT%"
REG ADD HKCU\CurrentSwVersion /v SwVersion /t REG_SZ /d %VERSION% /f

exit 0
```

Sorry to bother once again. Please tell me am i applying the suggesting of @Squashman properly in my dynamic script? Please help i have spent 5-6 hrs to make trial and error.

Comment: Use this line of code in your batch file: `set "EMS_INSTALL_ROOT=C:\Program Files (x86)\TOOLS\EMS\swVersion.txt"`.  Notice how the quotes are being used.

Comment: @Squashman I can't believe on my eyes. it started working. Can you please tell what it make difference with such quotes?

Comment: Run your batch file from a cmd prompt.  You will see the error plain as day.  `'Files' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`  You are double double quoting, because you assigned double quotes to your variable.  So as soon as it sees the next space it thinks that is the command it has to execute.  The commands are executed based on spaces separating the arguments.

Comment: Essentially the IF command is seeing this as the file it has to check because of the leading set of double quotes. `IF NOT EXIST ""C:\Program`. So the next argument after the space is the command it wants to execute.

Comment: @Squashman It worked with the example script but failing for dynamic script. I have edited the question, please have a look at it. I'm really in big trouble.